# Is there a separate section in Hades for the uncircumcised according to Ezekiel 32?

Tags: ezekiel

> Ezekiel 32:17 In the twelfth year, on the fifteenth day of the month, the word of the Lord came to me: 18“Son of man, wail for the hordes of Egypt and consign to the earth below both her and the daughters of mighty nations, along with those who go down to the **pit**. 19Say to them, ‘Are you more favored than others? Go down and be laid among the **uncircumcised**.’ 20They will fall among those killed by the sword. The sword is drawn; let her be dragged off with all her hordes. 21From within the realm of the dead the mighty leaders will say of Egypt and her allies, ‘They have come down and they lie with the **uncircumcised**, with those killed by the sword.’

Is the pit the same as Hades?

Comment: Uncircumcised = foreigners. An idiom for ‘non-jews’. Those who aren’t ‘of The one true God’. Those outside of covenant.

Comment: Eze 32 is simply saying that when we die we all end up in the same condition - in the gave or "pit" = sheol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "Hades" is not a Hebrew word or a belief in the Hebrew bible. It is a belief from Greek mythology and is the name of their false god of the underworld. I believe by "Hades" you mean Sheol, in which case, "the Pit" is often an alternate name for Sheol. Ezekiel is not saying that the uncircumcised go to a separate section of Sheol, rather that they also go to Sheol. The use of the term "uncircumcised" was seen as an insult as they were seen as uncivilized or unclean. Those slain by the sword are also seen as unclean as the Hebrew word for them is
חללים which comes from the root חל״ל which means "to desecrate." Thus, Ezekiel is saying that Egypt will go down to the Sheol along with people seen as uncivilized or unclean.